# ib_insync "contract can't be hashed"

Tags: ib-insync

A process I have that's been running for a couple of years suddenly stopped working.
I avoided updating much in the way of python and packages to avoid that..

I've now updated ib_insync to the latest version, and no improvement. debugging a little gives me this:

the code
import ib_insync as ibis
ib = ibis.IB()
contract = ibis.Contract()
contract.secType = 'STK'
contract.currency = 'USD'
contract.exchange = 'SMART'
contract.localSymbol = 'AAPL'
ib.qualifyContracts(contract)

Result:
File "/Users/macuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ib_insync/client.py", line 244, in send
if field in empty:
File "/Users/macuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ib_insync/contract.py", line 153, in **hash**
raise ValueError(f'Contract {self} can't be hashed')
ValueError: Contract Contract(secType='STK', exchange='SMART', currency='USD', localSymbol='AAPL') can't be hashed
Exception ignored in: <bound method IB.**del** of <IB connected to 127.0.0.1:7497 clientId=6541>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/macuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ib_insync/ib.py", line 233, in **del**
File "/Users/macuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ib_insync/ib.py", line 281, in disconnect
File "/Users/macuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/logging/**init**.py", line 1306, in info
File "/Users/macuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/logging/**init**.py", line 1442, in _log
File "/Users/macuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/logging/**init**.py", line 1452, in handle
File "/Users/macuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/logging/**init**.py", line 1514, in callHandlers
File "/Users/macuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/logging/**init**.py", line 863, in handle
File "/Users/macuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/logging/**init**.py", line 1069, in emit
File "/Users/macuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/logging/**init**.py", line 1059, in _open
NameError: name 'open' is not defined

```
| => python --version
Python 3.6.4 :: Anaconda, Inc.
```

Comment: I'm afraid your debugging info isn't very helpful without code. That said, the last line seems to indicate the problem: "name 'open' is not defined". Please consider providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not OP, but have had a similar problem. I am attempting to send an order to IB using ib_insync.

```
contract = Stock('DKS','SMART','USD')
order = LimitOrder('SELL', 1, 1)

try:
    ib.qualifyContracts(contract)
    trade = ib.placeOrder(contract, order)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Here is the exception that is returned:

```
Contract Stock(symbol='DKS', exchange='SMART', currency='USD') can't be hashed
```

I understand that lists and other mutable can't be hashed, but I don't understand why this wouldn't work. It pretty clearly follows the examples in the ib_insync docs.

Answer (score 0):

FYI - I was able to resolve this issue by updating to the latest ib_insync version. Perhaps this will help you as well.